# Twitter widget covers up another div that might appear over it . How to make twitter widget appear under?

Tags: html, css, twitter, transparency, wmode

I'm sure a lot of people use the twitter widget that twitter provides.

Here's the code they provide:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script> 
<script> 
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 3,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 420,
  height: 250,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#666666'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('apumpkinpatch').start();
</script>
```

You can see an example here how when you click the "feedback" tab on left side of screen, the twitter widget appears over the div. Any idea what I can do to prevent [this](http://apumpkinpatch.com/)?

I think the class for the widget is `.twtr-doc` according to the inspector. Anyone know if there is a `css` attribute I should be adding to it to stop this from happening?

**EDIT -:** took out IE part of question to just open it up in another question so I can mark the first answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: the twitter widget being on top of the feedback div, you need to use [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property in your styles to correct this.

Try adding z-index:100 to your feedback div. I do not have IE or I would help you debug that.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should submit the other part of the questions separately